# How to write a request letter in Russian?

Tags: этикет

I came across a Russian forum that required an invitation code (код приглашения) to be eligible for registration, so I have to write a request email in Russian to the forum admin in order to get the code. It has to be written in Russian, but I don't have enough confidence in composing a mail that is fluent and appropriate in Russian yet. I'm wondering what is the structure of this kind of mail that follow the basic email etiquette in Russia? I'd really appreciate a example.

Comment: Welcome to Russian.SE! Please note that the questions you ask here should be reasonably scoped. Please provide specific sentences and phrases you are having difficulties with. Thanks!

Comment: Usually the code is sent to you by an automatic system after you complete a form. There is no need for admin invitation.

Comment: Can you write the link to this forum? We can help you to register or write a letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получать приглашение - всегда сложное дело ;)

Я носитель языка и на вашем месте я написал бы так (замените угловые скобки на соответствующие имена и названия):

```
Здравствуйте! Меня зовут <ваше имя> , я из <страна в родительном
падеже>, изучаю русский и давно интересуюсь вашим сервисом.
Не могли бы вы выслать мне приглашение, пожалуйста?
Буду очень благодарен!
_________________________ 
С уважением, <(ваше имя)>
```

Comment: That's a reasonable example but it might be a bit more appropriate to use the word "приглашение" instead of "инвайт". The latter is direct and very recent loan from English and not yet widely accepted in official correspondence.